# Enterprise Library Exception Handling application blocks

Tags: exception, enterprise-library

Where can I find some good examples on 
1) How to configure Enterprise Library Exception Handling application blocks and
2) How to Log an exception error messages to a text file

(I am using VS2008 asp.net3.5, C# to develop a web application
and uses Enterprise library 4.1 for Exception Handling and Error logging )

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [the hands-on labs for Entlib 4.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=ab3f2168-fea1-4fc2-b40c-7867d99d4b6a). They include lots of examples on how to use the blocks, including the exception block.

Comment: Lab 1 from HOL for the Exception Handling Block is Logging Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, The Hands on Labs are a good place to start.  You could also take a look at the Quick Starts.  When you install the source code you have the option of installing the Quick Starts.  There is an ExceptionHandlingWithLoggingQuickStart project there that you would probably find useful.